# Access to fields of custum RESTAdapter

Tags: ember.js, websocket, adapter, ember-data

I would to reuse my websocket connection defined inside my custum Adapted. The Adapted is defined as follow:

```
DS.SocketAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({ 

  socket: undefined,

  init: function(){    
    this.socket = new App.WebSocketHandler("ws://my-cool-connection");
    this._super();
  },

  find: function (store, type, id){
    // override: use this.socket     
  },

  findAll: function (store, type){ 
    // override: use this.socket
  },

  createRecord: function(store, type, record){
    // override: use this.socket
  }
});
```

The **socket** attribute holds an active WebSocket connection. The Adapter is really helpful to keep data updated when DS.Model changes. But.. what is the best way to reuse my connection outside the Adapter? Can I access to **socket** property?

Any ideas? Thanks.

My store:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12, adapter: DS.SocketAdapter.create({})
});
```

Comment: Why do you want to reuse your connection? The `socket` attribute should be accessible on the adapter.

Comment: Yes. But I have the necessity to send a message to another client connected to the server via WebSocket. In a few words I am writing a chat application; the DS.Model represents the user profile but I would send a message to the server (using my own protocol in order to don't affect the Model behavour)

Comment: I don't know what are the models inside your app, but I could imagine something like this:  App.User has many App.Message. In which case you can reuse your socket in your adapter when creating/updating a message.

Comment: Thank you! I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not store a reference at the application level like this?

```
App.mySharedSocket = Ember.Object.extend({});
```

...

```
DS.SocketAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({ 
  socket: undefined,
  init: function(){
    this.socket = new App.WebSocketHandler("ws://my-cool-connection");
    App.set('mySharedSocket', this.socket);
    ...
```

EDIT: after the comments about encapsulation here a different solution, you could create a Mixin and use it for every object that needs access to the shared socket, composition pattern. example:

```
App.SharedSocket = Ember.Mixin.create({
    socket: null,
    getSocket: function() {
        // Lazy creation
        if(!this.get('socket')) {
            this.set('socket', new App.WebSocketHandler("ws://my-cool-connection"));
        }
        return this.get('socket');
    }
});

DS.SocketAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend(App.SharedSocket, {
  init: function(){
    // do what you want with your socket
    var mySocket = this.getSocket();
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for replay. This is an acceptable response. However I think I should take care about `encapsulation` so I will pass through the DS.Model, for my purpose

Comment: i added one more idea for inspiration only :)

Comment: Wow Thanks for the idea! I appreciate it very much! I should learn a bit more about custum Mixin! Thanks twice!